# ko.extender to validate input field as number (whole) or return original value

Tags: knockout.js

I am trying to validate an input field to check if the entered value is a whole number. If the input is invalid, I just need to reset to original value.

What should I be returning in the write function below?

```
ko.extenders.checkInput = function (target, options) {
    var result = ko.computed({
    read: target,
    write: function (newValue) {
        /*-------------*/   
        }

    }).extend({ notify: 'always' });

    result(target());

    return result;
};
```

Comment: The write function doesn't need to return anything. It's just used to write a value to the target observable.

Comment: Should the validations be in read then? e.g. isNaN check and (number%1) for whole number check so that I can send a valid/error message back.

Comment: If you want to prevent the value from being written to the target observable the write function is the place to do that; if it passes validation update the target, otherwise don't. As for messages there's nothing that handles that by default in an extender. You can set some other observable property on your view-model though and display that on your screen somewhere.

Comment: Take a look a this simple example of a required field extender from Ryan Niemeyer. http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/p7kxw/